# Examining a Visio Shape.Cell collection

Tags: vba, visio

I need some suggestion on how to query a VISIO Shape.cells collection in vb or vba.

I have written an application to drop a shape on a page and I can change its name after dropping it on the page. Now I want to examine the shape cells collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visio shape cells are broken up into different sections.  Such sections might include User Cells, Actions, or Character settings.  There are also a series of named cells that you can only (I think) access through the name (i.e. PinX or PinY).

So to query a shape's cells, you first have to figure out what section of cells you're talking about.  To loop through a cell section, you first get the number of rows in the section, then loop through that section using the CellsSRC method on the shape object.

```
Dim TheShp As Visio.Shape
Set TheShp = ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
Dim TheSec As Visio.Section
Dim TheCell As Visio.Cell
Set TheSec = TheShp.Section(visSectionUser)
Dim RowNum As Long
For RowNum = 0 To TheSec.Count - 1
    Set TheCell = TheShp.CellsSRC(visSectionUser, RowNum, 0)
    Debug.Print TheCell.Formula
    Debug.Print TheCell.Result(visNone)
Next CellNum
```

Looping in this way can be slow if there are a lot of cells in a lot of shapes.  If you need to access the formulas or results of a large number of cells, there are GetFormulas and GetResults methods on the Page object that take arrays of SRC values and shape ID's that will pull all those Formulas/Results at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try what you suggest.